# How to recover Google App Engine's "default service account"

Tags: google-app-engine

I have mistakenly deleted the default "app engine service account" for my project - {id}@**appspot.gserviceaccount.com**
Is there a way to recover it without resetting/recreating my project on Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<del>Unfortunately at this time, there is no way to recover the default App Engine service account.  The solution is as you say creating a new project and redeploying your code there.</del>

Should you wish to see this deletion prevented or default service account recreation made possible in the future, I strongly urge you to file a feature request on the [App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) while providing this example as a business case.

**UPDATE**: As filed by the OP, a feature request now exists on the App Engine public issue tracker as [Issue 13085](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13085).  Please ***star*** this issue to receive updates on its progress.

**UPDATE 2**: As part of the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/), one can now use the [`apps.repair`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair) API to attempt to address issues of default Cloud Storage buckets and App Engine service accounts.  I would recommend trying this API before creating a new project and redeploying.  I'm leaving this as an addendum and not the primary solution as it's not guaranteed to solve the issue.

**UPDATE 3** It is now possible to undelete service accounts.  As per the [**Undeleting a service account** documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-delete-undelete), a service account may be restored if:

> The service account was deleted less than 30 days ago

and

> There is no existing service account with the same name as the deleted service account.

Comment: Thanks very much. An issue has been created - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13085

Comment: What to do when you've passed the 30 day window to recover the deleted service account? If creating a new one is the solution then how to set that to default App Engine service account?

Answer (score 12):

You can now recover the deleted service accounts from https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete

you have to get the UniqueID of the service account from https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

Comment: You saved the day. Just a note: you can use the API explorer on the right of the page to authenticate your request, i initially tried to use Postman but that resulted in a 404 due to no credentials being passed. The API Explorer takes care of all this for you.

Comment: I recommend also the usage of API explorer on the right, it does the OAuth for you

Comment: Thank you for quick solution. This saves us lot of time. Yes I also recommend to use API explorer.

Comment: Wow I didn't know this activity panel existed, you saved me here! Just happened to remove a role where I shouldn't have and broke AppEngine in the process... Thanks to you I could identify the removed role and put it back.

Answer (score 2):

## Recover

You can undelete service accounts. You will need the service account's unique ID. If you don't have it, you can find it on Google Cloud Logging.

You can find `Logging` service here on the side menu:

[image: Google Logging, where to find]

Then you will need to filter by date and type `service account` to find the exact moment the service was deleted.

[image: Google Logging - how to find the UNIQUE ID of a deleted service account]

Then you can either

### Option 1: Use Google Cloud Command Line

You can run the command line by installing it on your computer (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install). Or you can run it online using the `Active Shell` offered by Google Cloud Platform.

[image: Where to find Google Cloud Active Shell - gcloud]

The command you want to run is the following.

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete 12345678901234567890
```

### Option 2: Use Google Cloud API

Using `curl`, call the API with the following command.

You will need to change `API_KEY`, `PROJECT_ID` and `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_UID` for real values.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d "" \
"https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_UID:undelete"
```

You can get the API_KEY from Google Cloud Command Line:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Again you can either have `gcloud` installed on your local machine or you can use it online with the `Active Shell`.

[image: Where to find Google Cloud Active Shell - gcloud]

Comment: same 30 days limit

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the default service account UniqueID, there is another solution.

Simply disable the **App Engine Admin API** and enable the same after some time. This will create a new default service account. Please note that this will delete all the associated resources.

(To enable/disable an API: Menu -> API & Services -> Dashboard -> Enable APIs and Services -> Search for that API -> Enable/Disable)

Comment: is it save to disable it if there is dependence on the API ?
got this error
```ERROR: (gcloud.services.disable) FAILED_PRECONDITION: The service compute.googleapis.com is depended on by the following active service(s): anthos.googleapis.com,container.googleapis.com,dataflow.googleapis.com,file.googleapis.com,redis.googleapis.com; Please specify disable_dependent_services=true if you want to proceed with disabling all services.
```

Comment: yep! there's no reason to track down the deleted account and undelete it. you can just create a new default service account, and everything should be fine

Comment: How long you should wait to re-enable it again? It seems like it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your Account is deleted less than `30 days` you can recover it via cloud console

Go to Cloud Console Open Terminal :

Write :

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete 100214681451516381413
```

100214681451516381413 this is the Deleted **Account UID** .

If You Don't know the Deleted Account ID then GO `IAM` and Search With Your Deleted Email Address you will find-out the `UID` there .

Thanks .