# Error on google function deploy, service account doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Please can you help me, I'm receiving this error when I'm trying to deploy a google cloud function:

```
HTTP Error: 400, Default service account 'project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account.
```

The command used to deploy is:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

A temporary solution is fine, but if you can help me to solve it permanently is better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message says "disable and enable the cloud functions API".  Have you tried doing a web search for that to see if there is documentation for that?

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried disabling and reenabling the cloud function API to no avail. I disabled my service account because the credentials were leaked and the only solution I see below involves undeleting my compromised credentials.  How do I "specify a different account"?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the App Engine default service account was deleted. It looks like this: `{project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

So I had to restore the service account like this:

> You can now recover the deleted service accounts from https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete
>
> you have to get the UniqueID of the service account from https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55277567/888881

The API explorer is an easy way to use the IAM API: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Comment: I deleted my default service account because the credentials were inadvertently posted in a public place.  I don't want to undelete the key but create a new secure one.  Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling to resolve this issue, then I raised a case with Google.

here is a detailed article of my learnings :
https://medium.com/@ashirazee/http-error-400-default-service-account-appspot-gserviceaccount-com-accd178ea32a

Firstly navigate to Google Cloud Platform and view your service accounts.

try and find <project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' in your list of service accounts for the firebase project, it is linked to the App Engine.

if '@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' is missing you can not deploy anything(SEE EMAIL WITH GOOGLE BELOW), if it isn't, check and see if it's enabled, try disabling it and enabling it again.

@appspot.gserviceaccount.com is pre-installed by default, regardless of a paid account or not. try and recall if at any time you may have deleted it after or before deployment.

Now if you have for any reason deleted it over a period of more than 30 days than you can not retrieve it, and you must create a new firebase project. However, if it is within 30 days you can undelete it.

EMAIL FROM GOOGLE:

Email #1
"
Hello Ali

I am checking the logs of your project, unfortunately the service account was deleted on Ma, there is no chance to recover it nor recreate it

The only workaround available is to create a new project and deploy the service desired there. I know this could not be the best option for you nevertheless it is the way this works by design.

Do not hesitate to write back if you have more questions.

Cheers,"

Email #2,

"Hello Ali

I am glad to read that you have been able to deploy your functions successfully, unfortunately that service account cannot be recovered after 30 days of being deleted and that is the only solution. If you have other questions, please let us know by contacting us again through our support channel.

Cheers,"

---

lastly here is a helpful command line that will help you debug this, however, it won't help if there is no service account, it'll just highlight the obvious:

firebase deploy --only functions --debug

this was my error:

"HTTP Error: 400, Default service account '<project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Clo
ud Functions API), or specify a different account."

Answer (score 1):

Following the error message, you could enable the API by console accessing this [url](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com) and enable the api.

Or by gcloud command:

```
gcloud services --project <project_id> enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com
```

Comment: Worked for error "BadRequestException: 400 Service account PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

As the other stated, sadly, you need to use the default service account.

If within the 30 days period, you can use this tutorial to find and undelete the service acc: Read this guide to get https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account

You have to enter the commands through the Google Cloud Console (one of the buttons will open a terminal on the right of the top blue app bar)

Comment: Thanks @ForestG this really saved the day, waking up to an issue in the middle of night just to find out that one of the team members had accidentally deleted the account and failed to communicate the same.

Answer (score 1):

New answer from 2023!

You still can not create/restore the default service account after it has been deleted for 30 days, but you can change the account that Functions are looking for

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account

1. Go ahead and create a new service account.
2. Manually create a function with the same name you need to deploy in the console UI
3. Set the service account to the one you created in step 1
4. Deploy the function with the default code it provides.
5. From the terminal run with an account with >= Editor role

```html
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding your_account@your_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member=user:{firebase/gcloud cli account email} --role=role
s/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

6. Deploy the function as you normally would. Everything should work now.

Answer (score -2):

try to  select **Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location**  in Setting of Firebase. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGfYh.png)

Comment: This is not possible. You can't change it once selected.

Comment: sorry i write change instead of select , thanks for correction ,  i  have faced same issue bcz i did not  select GCP ,

Comment: I still don't understand what you are suggesting as a solution.

Comment: **Error on google function deploy, service account doesn't exist 
** i faced this issue, because i did not select Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location in Setting,