# how to restore default service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

similar question: [Error on google function deploy, service account doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912513/error-on-google-function-deploy-service-account-doesnt-exist/63283785)    but I didnt delete anythin so no ans applies to me

I am following the guide https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

in step https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#store-secret-values-in-secret-manager     Configure access to the secret:

however by look into IAM page(with  Include Google-provided role grants ),
I discover service account `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` doesn't exist

**how to restore this default account**? even if I start a new project, this default account still not there.

I have try to initize a computer engine, the service account is in format `projectID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`   but not in  `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Why do you think it is not there? Are you getting an error message? Google managed service accounts do not automatically display in the GUI. Go to IAM. Then click the **Include Google-provided role grants** located on the right side of the panel. You can also use the CLI to list service accounts.

Comment: @JohnHanley   look into IAM page(with Include Google-provided role grants ), I confirm service account PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com doesn't exist......

Comment: Have you already enabled App Engine or Cloud Functions? Otherwise there is no reason to have the appspot service account

Comment: Please include all information requested. What error message? Why do you think the service account has been deleted? 1) If you enabled the services that require a service account and you did not delete it, then it exists. With details we can help you otherwise we will keep guessing.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that the projects need to have some app engine created  in order for that service account to be created