# GCP: Service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com was not found

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, service-accounts, google-iam

I'm trying to deploy a webpage based on Next.js with Firebase hosting via the Firebase CLI.
The API route is not available for static pages created using the `next export` method, so I'm trying to deploy Next.js using FIrebase's webframeworks function.
However, when I create the function in Cloud Functions, if I check the logs, I get the following message:

```
status: {
  code: 5
  message: "Service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER-. 
  compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com was not found."
}
```

The service account for developer.gserviceaccount.com was removed more than 30 days ago and cannot be undeleted.
Can I create a new developer.gserviceaccount.com service account?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Follow these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-default-service-accounts#recover_the_default_service_account

Comment: I have already read this. Do I need to create a VM instance? VM instance is not exist.

Comment: Read or followed the instructions? Put some effort into your question by showing what you tried and the results.

Comment: @JohnHanley This document tells me how to modify a VM instance.
I thought that when I deployed with firebase hosting, it would automatically create a VM instance for me.
I created a VM instance, assigned a service account, and it deployed successfully.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to create the function in cloud function because your service account for `developer.gserviceaccount.com` was removed more than 30 days ago and cannot be found.

You need to assign the service account to cloud function by following steps :

- [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create#creating) or select an existing service account to set as the new Compute Engine default service account.
- Once your service account is created then attach this service account to your cloud functions by following this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) and refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76541849/19230181) by Spencer Easton.
- Even after doing the above two steps if it's not working then create the VM by following the link Provided by @John Hanely.
- Go into https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard and disable and re-enable the compute engine API. This will take a few moments, but after the GCE API is re-enabled you should be able to create VMs through the Cloud Shell again and be able to reproduce this.

Comment: I created a VM instance, assigned a service account, and it deployed successfully. Thanks!