# Unable to create Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine

When I tried to create a Google App Engine application via `gcloud app create` at terminal on Ubuntu and on the web, it gives me the following error,

"ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists."

I guess the reason why I don't have the default service account because I deleted a default project on GCP which was made when I started using GCP, not sure though.

I made a service account at IAM & admin menu, but not work. Any idea?

Comment: follow the steps properly there shouldn't have any issues. recently I have created few projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I found this answer, it didn't work for me.
[How to recover Google App Engine's "default service account"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944341/how-to-recover-google-app-engines-default-service-account)

But I didn't delete the default google app engine service account, it was missing at the first place. Maybe because I tried to create a GAE app on the web and left the page before it's done. I don't know.

Anyway, I make a new project and create a GAE app via gcloud cli, and now it's good to go.