# AppEngine service account cannot be generated but it exist

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I created my first app engine and I think I deleted wrong service account. I was able to recover it following ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944341/how-to-recover-google-app-engines-default-service-account#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=Unfortunately%20at%20this%20time%2C%20there,and%20redeploying%20your%20code%20there).

However I still can't redeploy app engine (or deploy any new engine in the project). Here is the error I'm getting. As I said, I managed to run `projects.serviceAccounts.undelete` endpoint but it doesn't help. Any idea what could be done to get this working again?

```
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.

 ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/{project}/services/orch/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'c
ontent-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 17 May 2021 19:47:03 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORI
GIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '500', 'content-length': '147', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "AppEngine service account cannot be generated for p~{project}.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

edit 1:

I went to the source code of app engine and under the debugger there is info:
Please fix the following issue and try again:

```
App Engine service account
An error has occurred while adding the App Engine default service account. Visit this page and manually add the <project-name>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com account with editor role.
```

however when I try to add it I get

```
Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, Google Workspace account, or Cloud Identity account.
```

Comment: Easiest way: delete your project and create a new one. Or try a `gcloud beta app repair`

Comment: thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. I tried repair and I got `app engine service account cannot be generated for p~<project>` I was hoping to avoid deleting a project because there is more resources there but seems like not much hope left.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have inadvertently deleted the default service account,this could cause the products which rely on App Engine (including Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler) to not work as expected, as you are experiencing now.

Please follow the below steps if 30 days has not elapsed since deleting the account:

- My best recommendation is that you deploy your resources in a different project to work around this issue.
- However if there is significant investment made into deploying the account you can reach out to GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM SUPPORT by using the  following link[1], as depending upon the severity or type of your deployment ,there could be changes made to undelete it completely. This process can be done upto 30 days after deletion.

Incase 30 days have elapsed since the deletion of the account, Unfortunately it is not possible to recover the account.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/contact
[2]https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting